# Pixelated text chart using Charting Library in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts, itext

I want to create a chart with this Library, I have created one but the text is pixelated so the feel is very ugly.

I'm passing this charts to a PDF file with iText Sharp to create a report.

Here is the code:

```
private static byte[] ObtenerBarraDoble(IList<ValorBarraDTO> valores)
    {
        var newColor1 = Color.FromArgb(187, 189, 191);
        var newColor2 = Color.FromArgb(0, 138, 209);
        using (var graficoPie = new Chart { Height = 200, Width = 600, RenderType = RenderType.BinaryStreaming })
        {
            var chartAreaPie = new ChartArea();
            chartAreaPie.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MMM\nhh:mm";
            chartAreaPie.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
            chartAreaPie.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
            chartAreaPie.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 2);
            chartAreaPie.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 2);
            graficoPie.ChartAreas.Add(chartAreaPie);

            var serieNuevo = new Series("Cartera Actual")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
                XValueMember = "label",
                YValueMembers = "valor1",
                Color = newColor1,
                Legend = "Cartera Actual",
                IsValueShownAsLabel = true,


            };

            graficoPie.Series.Add(serieNuevo);

            var serie = new Series("Cartera Recomendada")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
                XValueMember = "label",
                YValueMembers = "valor2",
                Color = newColor2,
                Legend = "Cartera Propuesta",
                IsValueShownAsLabel =true,

            };

            graficoPie.Series.Add(serie);
            graficoPie.DataSource = valores;

            return PdfHelper.ChartABinario(graficoPie);
        }
    }
```

Here is ChartABinario method:

```
internal static byte[] ChartABinario(Chart graficoPie)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            graficoPie.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] retorno = ms.ToArray();
            return retorno;
        }
    }
```

This creates the chart and it's displaying it well, but the text is bad. What can I do to make that the text doesn't display pixelated letters?

Comment: The code that you've posted only shows the logical creation of the chart but not the actual file that gets produced. Instead of the above you'll need to post the contents of `PdfHelper.ChartABinario()`. But the ultimate solution will be that you need to increase the effective DPI of the chart. If the chart control supports a DPI, use that, otherwise you'll need to create a larger chart, maybe 600x1800 or something similar.

Comment: Thanks! There i posted the class, i can't find the way to do what you say. I change the size of the chart but it doesn't fit in the PDF file.